# CSS: Filter Looks Messed Up In IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter

I am trying to implement that effect, that an image is greyscale, but on hover it should be colored. Basically it's working, but in IE8 it's showing a strange black border around *some* images (but not all).

Here's a [Demopage](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8840372/greyscale-hover.html).

So you can see on the VentureBeat logo it looks as expected, but the openWebasia logo is messed up. It seems to me, that something with the image is wrong, but I can't figure out what. Here's a [screenshot of the page in IE8](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8840372/states.png).

Does anybody know why that is happening?

Edit: The transition on the first logo is also a little bit messed up. It really seems that there is a problem with the image.

Comment: I don't see any distortions in IE8. I've also tried changing page zoom but it looks OK.

Comment: Really? Well, I've attached a screenshot of IE8 to my question, so you can see what the problem is. Does it then seem to be a problem with my IE? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've exported the transparent PNGs once again with Photoshop and now they seem to be ok. Still it would be interesting to know what the problem was...